# How to accept user input and run an 'if statement' on one line of code

Tags: python

I want to create a more pythonic code line to take a string input from a user and then check to see if the string is a palinadrome (i.e. a reversable word like "racecar").
I have tried this code below and functionally it works ok, but I want to improve it:

```
word = "Racecar".lower()
print("Palindrome" if word == word[::-1] else "Not Palindrome")
```

But ideally what I want is to be able to produce a code line something like this:

```
word = input() if word == word[::-1],print("Palindrome" else "Not Palindrome")
```

I can't get the code to work and need some advise on how to structure the code accept an input and then perform an IF function  work with a result being printed out.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Using less lines doesn't make something Pythonic. It can make it harder to read and maintain though.

Comment: The first version looks reasonable. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the second version.

Comment: Python *prefers* more, shorter, simpler lines over code golfing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.8 has the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) (Assignment expressions),

```
print("Palindrome" if (c := input().lower()) == c[::-1] else "Not palindrome")
```